# How to cast INT32 to INT during a SQL select through a LINQ data context?

Tags: c#, linq, casting, executequery

I have the following statement:

```
someList = dc.ExecuteQuery<MyCustomType>(@"Select Id As ProductId, Name From ivProduct").ToList();
```

Id in the database is stored as int32, when my Id property of MyCustomType is INT. Is there a way to cast that int32 to int during a select?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int` and `Int32` are the same type. No cast is necessary.

**Edit**

If your column is a `smallint`, that corresponds to an `Int16` (or `short` using the C# keyword). You can either use the `CONVERT` statement as you are now, or you can change the property on your object to be a `short`.

Comment: Thx for this. Just looked at the exceptiona again, made a mistake - SQL attribute is of type smallint when my property is of type int.

Comment: Yea the SQL convert has fixed the issue. THank you

Answer (score 0):

Doing `Convert(INT,Id) As ProductId` did the job. Would be good to see a way to do it without SQL Convert. Might try adding cast to properties